# Displaying HTML Body on a page using ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

Say I have the following code in my database (user input):

```
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <body>testing website</body>
</html>
```

And I fetched it correctly from my database using ReactJS. How can I display this in say: 'localhost:3000/play'? I don't want it to be rendered as raw data just like the code but I want it to actually render the html body as a website. (Title set to Test, and displays a small text: testing website). How can I do that in ReactJS? I already have /play configured and I just want to know how to display it there in the index.js file. I tried something like `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />` but it didn't work.

Comment: make sure your ```template``` is a json in form of ```{__html: 'First &middot; Second'}```. the ```__html``` attribute is important.

Comment: What I am doing is,  `const innerHtml = { __html: snapshot.val() }
            return(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={innerHtml} />)` and when I log innerHtml I get this `{__html: "<html>   <title>Test</title>   <body>testing website</body> </html>"}`

Comment: https://jaketrent.com/post/update-body-class-react/

Answer (score 1):

So, I fixed it with the following: 
In a separate function:

`db.getHTMLBody(key).then(snapshot => {
            this.setState({ body: snapshot.val() })
        })`

then in the render:

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.body }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
const innerHtml = { __html: escape(snapshot.val()) } 
return(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={innerHtml} />)
```